# Handle an external API event from a method C#

Tags: c#, events, handle

I'm using Advance Steel API for a library I'm creating and I need to somehow handle an event.

This is the class the API provides

```
public class OpenDatabase : IDisposable {
    public OpenDatabase();

    ~OpenDatabase();

    public UnitsSet Units { get; set; }
    public Database CADDatabase { get; }
    public ASObjectsAPI.OpenDatabase* Native { get; set; }
    public IntPtr Internal { get; }

    ...
    public event DatabaseEventHandler ObjectAppended;
    ...

    ...
    public void objectAppended(Database db, CADAccess.FilerObject fo);
    ...
    protected void raise_ObjectAppended(object value0, DatabaseEventArgs value1);

    public delegate void DatabaseEventHandler(object source, DatabaseEventArgs args);
    public delegate void IdMappingEventHandler(object source, IdMappingEventArgs args);
}
```

I need to handle the event ObjectAppended from another method. How should I proceed? I don't know how to work with events.

I guess the method I need to use is objectAppended(Database, CAD.Access.FilerObject) because I need to get that FilerObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events), you'll learn how to subscribe to events like this:

```
public void SomeMethod() {
    yourOpenDatabase.ObjectAppended += ObjAppendHandler;
}

public void ObjAppendHandler(Database db, CADAccess.FillerObject fo) {
    //Insert code to handle your event...
}
```

Comment: Not working, I get an error when doing
    yourOpenDatabase.ObjectAppended += ObjAppendHandler;

Edit: Changed ObjAppendHandler parameters to object and EventArgs and it looks like it's working.

Comment: Well i'm happy that worked ! If you could accept my answer that would be great !